# Fatal: File system overrun error with mkxfs

Tags: qnx, qnx-neutrino, qnx-ifs

I am trying to format image file with mkxfs command on Windows. I am always getting File System overrun error. 
http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.utilities/topic/m/mkxfs.html
Command executed:

```
mkxfs.exe -t qnx6fsimg  buildfile  fs build.img
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that the specified size of the image is not large enough to store the contents it is supposed to have.

This usually happens because the total physical size of the contents / entities specified in your "buildfile" is more than the size of the "build.img" specified in your disk configuration file.